# How to make an interruptible delay in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some cells on a spreadsheet which, when selected, open a text box.

I don't want the box to open if, for instance, the user is tabbing through the cell without stopping, so I'd like for the Worksheet_SelectionChange to wait for two seconds before opening the text box. If the Selection moves before then, the timer would be interrupted and start over for the new cell.

I've been trying to experiment with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If (Intersect(Target, [rSpecialInstr]) Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    frmSpecialInstr.Show

End Sub
```

...but I'm having a pre-existing problem with the macro stopping at random times, so I can't test this trick. (I'm hoping the community will lead me to answer by the time I've solved thatother issue.)

I *suspect* that once the Selection lands on a cell and starts this timer, I can't actually move the Selection again until the 2 seconds pass. Can anyone confirm that?

Is there a better approach to this task?

Comment: You can use `Application.OnTime` to schedule a macro which will show the text box.  Use a global variable to keep track of whether you need to cancel previous calls if the user tabs to a next cell before the code triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Dim d As Date

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'cancel any previous scheduled call
    If d > 0 Then
        Application.OnTime d, "Sheet1.test", , schedule:=False
        d = 0
    End If

    'schedule?
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        d = Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
        Application.OnTime d, "Sheet1.test"
    End If

End Sub

Sub test()
    d = 0
    MsgBox "ok"
End Sub
```